# IllegalArgument Exception TomEE

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-tomee

I downloaded TomEE 1.7.1 and installed. While bringing the server up an IllegalArgumentException is thrown. 
 What could be the issue as I have not deployed any app yet.

```
INFO: Using 'openejb.jdbc.datasource-    creator=org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.EventObject.<init>(EventObject.java:52)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent.<init>(PropertyChangeEvent.java:41)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport$MoniterableHashMap.put(GlobalListenerSupport.java:412)
    at java.util.HashMap.putAllImpl(HashMap.java:746)
    at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:736)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.<init>(LinkedHashMap.java:112)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport$MoniterableHashMap.<init>(GlobalListenerSupport.java:403)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.addContextListener(GlobalListenerSupport.java:380)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.engineAdded(GlobalListenerSupport.java:224)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.serviceAdded(GlobalListenerSupport.java:201)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.start(GlobalListenerSupport.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.start(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:409)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatLoader.initialize(TomcatLoader.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener.install(ServerListener.java:168)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener.lifecycleEvent(ServerListener.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
```

This is all the stacktrace that is thrown out.

Comment: And your Java version is?

Comment: Did you do any changes to configuration files at all, say to add database configuration or something?

Comment: Class path set to Java 6 and there is no change in configuration files as my app donot use DB.

Comment: "Class path set to Java 6" I have no idea what that means. What did you do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Check el JRE_HOME variable environment. JRE_HOME most be reater a 5.
Tomcat EE display for example:

```
E:\Users\yo\Documents\apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.4\bin>startup.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "E:\Users\yo\Documents\apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.4"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "E:\Users\yo\Documents\apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.4"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "E:\Users\yo\Documents\apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.4\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
Using CLASSPATH:       "E:\Users\yo\Documents\apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.4\bin\bootstrap.jar;E:\Users\yo\Documents\ejecutables\apac
he-tomee-webprofile-1.7.4\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```

Check the version of JRE

-- Revisa la versión del JRE